# How to add Tooltip to jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, tooltip

I am using jqgrid to display data present in server how do i show description of data on mouse hover tool tip.

which is the best way to show tool tip on jqgrid?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tooltip shown in jqGrid on mouse hover is nothing more as the "title" atribute of the corresponding HTML elements. If you want change tooltip with [setCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods):

```
$("#list").setCell(rowid,'Name','','',{'title':'my custom tooltip on cell'});
```

where the `'Name'` is the column name where the tooltip will be set and `rowid` identify the row. For more informaion read [this answer](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/cell-tooltip-1/#p21526) including the references.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var setTooltipsOnColumnHeader = function (grid, iColumn, text){
      var thd = jQuery("thead:first", grid[0].grid.hDiv)[0];  
      jQuery("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th:eq(" + iColumn + ")", thd).attr("title", text);
     };


and just set tooltip on header column

setTooltipsOnColumnHeader ($("#empgrid"), 4, "Invoice No");
setTooltipsOnColumnHeader ("GRID NAME", "COLUMN" , "TOOLTIP TEXT");
```

Comment: For tooltips over header elements you can use `setLabel`. The signature of that call is similar to `setCell`, except that you don't specify rowid. Example: `$("#ajaxGrid").setLabel('Name', '', '', { 'title': "Project Name" });`