# jqgrid change column title attribute

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When I hover over a particular cell value, the hover value is same as the cell value. Can I change the hover text different from the cell value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the tooltip is the `title` attribute of the `<td>` elements. You can use [setCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method to change the tooltip (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638480/how-to-add-tooltip-to-jqgrid/4638855#4638855)). In more complex situations you can use [jQuery.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307523/how-to-set-the-tool-tip-on-jqgrid-mouse-over/4308440#4308440)) or you a tooltip plugin (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656980/external-tooltip-plug-in-on-jqgrid/4658572#4658572)).

Comment: This is what I am actually doing. I have values coming from database. One of the column's value is very long. So on display I want to show only 30 characters, and on hovering, I want to display all characters. Is this possible?

Comment: @user508518: If you set the column width so, that 30 charachters will be seen, you will have the same effect. The user will see first 30 characters in the cell and on hovering full text will be displayed. If you want truncate the text of the cell you can use `setCell` to change the text without changing of the tooltip.

Answer (score 5):

You can use cellattr attribute in the colModel for a column to set custom tooltip. For example

```
cellattr: function () { return ' title="my custom fixed tooltip for the column"'; }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Good solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can achieve by 2 steps

1. You can simply disable the default tool tip by setting `title:false`
2. write a global function and attached as a formatter in colModel

   ```
   var changeTitle = function(cellVal, options, rowObject){<br/>
       return  "&lt;div title='This is the cell value " + cellVal + "'>" + cellVal + "&lt;/div>";<br/>
   }

   colModel:[
   {...},<br/>
    {name:'priorityFlag', index:'priorityFlag', width:40, align:"center", formatter:   changeTitle },<br/>
   {...}]
   ```

There you go!...

Answer (score 0):

- You can right click title
- Learn a column ID name ex:PersonelGrid_DefViewMainPage
- Set you after grid load this code..

  `$("#PersonelGrid_DefViewMainPage").attr("title", "This is my Title.");`

it's work..