# Can jqGrid hover text be defined with AddRowData?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In jqGrid, is it possible to define a cell's Title (hover) text while adding row data?

```
var rowid;

for(var j=0;j&lt;10;j++)
  {
      rowid = jQuery.Guid.New();
      jQuery("#myJqGrid").jqGrid('addRowData',rowid,{Amount:"$"+j+".00",Date:"09/30/2015"});
  }
```

I'd prefer not to not to have to loop over the grid after it has completed, as the RowID and the data that is needed for the custom hover text are more readily available while the row is being added.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you just need to set custom tooltip on some *specific* cells in the grid you can use [setCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638480/how-to-add-tooltip-to-jqgrid/4638855#4638855) an example). If you want to set tooltips on all cells of some column, but with a custom rule (not just the same tooltip like the cell value), you can better use [cellattr](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options). For example you can use

```
{name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 70,
    cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
        return 'title="' + rawObject.name + ' (' + rawObject.note + ')"';
    }}
```

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataWithCustomTitle.htm) which display the following tooltips:

[image]

If you have an interest for performance you should not use old `addRowData` method which has many disadvantages:

- If you has date in input data and use formatter: 'date' then you have to use `formatoptions: {reformatAfterEdit: true}` to make the date correct formatted. You will find almost no information about the option in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#language_options).
- The data which you inserted row after the row will be all placed on the same page. To have correct local date paging you have to reload the grid one more time.
- Compare with the usage of `data` parameter in combination with `gridview: true` parameter (the de demo above) the building of grid contain with respect of `addRowData` is much slowly. You can see the difference if the number of row is large.
- During creating of the demo which use `cellattr` and `addRowData` I found a bug in the jqGrid in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.base.js#L2749) where two parameters `rowid` and `data` are swapped. I just now posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/small-bug-in-addrowdata/#p24608). So to use `cellattr` together with `addRowData` you have to make small modification in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`.

See the demo which use `addRowData` [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/addRowDataWithCustomTitle0.htm). If used modified version of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` (see my bug report for details)

Comment: > If you have an interest for performance you should not use old addRowData method.  Is there something that supersedes addRowData?

Comment: Also, the cellattr's rawObject is Undefined. Are custom modification required in order for that to work?

Comment: @Mark Maslar: Please, read my answer *carefully*. 1) I wrote that "the usage of `data` parameter in combination with `gridview: true` parameter" (see [the first demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataWithCustomTitle.htm)) gives you better performance as the usage of `addRowData` 2) To have no `undefined` results in tooltips **in case of usage `addRowData`** you have to use [the bug fix](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/small-bug-in-addrowdata/#p24608). It used in [the second demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/addRowDataWithCustomTitle0.htm).

Comment: @Oleg - have you used JqGrid with QTip before? What I like to do is on hover of and ID field which is a hyperlink, I like to call QTip and do a JSON.

Comment: @WebDev: I don't used QTip before, but it seems that you should just call `qtip` on the `<a>` element. To answer on your question you should post more details how you create hyperlinks in jqGrid and which tooltip you want to display. In any way you should post the definition of the column from `colModel` which contains the hyperlink.