# JQGrid: How can I mouseover/out only one column in the grid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, mouseover, mouseout

In my application I use JQGrid for listing some contacts. I need to show some details when user makes mouseover/mouseout over just one cloumn; for now I am using this code:

```
gridComplete: function () {
 jQuery('#MyGird').mouseover(function (e) {
      var rowId = $(e.target).parents("tr:first").attr('id');
      var rowdata = jQuery('#MyGird').getRowData(rowId);
      .....
      });
  jQuery('#MyGird').mouseout(function (e) {
      .....
       });
},
```

But this makes mouseover/mouseout over the entire row.

How can I mouseover/mouseout over just one column from the row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following selector grabs all first `<td>` elements from each `<tr>` within table#MyGird

```
$("td:first", $("#MyGird tr")).mouseover(function(e) {
```

if you don't wont the first row you could use the `:eq(index)` function like for the second column:

```
$("td:eq(1)", $("#MyGird tr")).mouseover(function(e) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
var ci = $.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target);
```

inside of any event handle to get the index of the current column. The index in `colModel` array (`jQuery('#MyGird').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel')`) can be used to get the value of corresponding `name` property of the column.

In the most cases `e.target` will be just DOM element of the cell ([`<td>`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_tabledata.asp)) and [$.jgrid.getCellIndex](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#common_functions_and_settings) will get back the value of [cellIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_cellindex.asp) property.

If the details which you want to show are just a text which are build from some information of the current row you can use [cellattr](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405248/can-jqgrid-hover-text-be-defined-with-addrowdata/7408355#7408355) for more information.