# JQGrid rendering performance

Tags: jqgrid, html-rendering

We have performance issues with JQgrid rendering. Please advise.

JQGrid v4.3.2, jquery-1.7.2.min.js, jquery-ui-1.8.1.sortable.min.js, jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js
Browser: IE6,7

Every user is shown data in 2 grids - actions and fyi's. Typical data range is ~300 rows in each grid. The list of columns could vary for user groups and hence the colModel structure is dynamic. After getting data we apply conditional styles to each row (to be bold or not etc) and change the number formatting.

Code sample for grid is as below:

```
jQuery('#ActionItems').jqGrid({
    url: 'http://actionsurl',
    mtype: 'GET',
    datatype: 'json',
    page: 1,
    colNames: actionsColNames,
    colModel: actionsColModel,
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    scrollrows: false,
    prmNames: { id: "PrimaryID" },
    hoverrows: false,
    jsonReader: { id: "PrimaryID" },
    sortname: 'CreateDt',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    gridComplete: function () {
        fnActionsGridComplete();
    },
    recordtext: "Displaying {1} of {2} Records",
    emptyrecords: "No data to view",
    emptyDataText: "No data found.",
    loadtext: "Loading...",
    autoWidth: true,
    rowNum: 1000,
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: groupingViewOp
});
```

Formatting code in fnActionsGridComplete():

1. Set column widths in %
2. Iterate thru rows to apply conditional css styles

   ```
   $("#Actions").find("tbody tr").each(function () {
       if ($(this)[0].id != '') { 
           var data = $(this).find('.IsItemNew').html();
               if(data == "Y") {            
               $(this).css("fontWeight", "bold");
               }                
       }                    
   });
   ```
3. Formatting for specific columns.

Currently we have performance issues for >200 rows of data in any grid. After analysis we found that formatting and rendering is taking most time.

Can you suggest any optimal way to improve performance here. (paging is no-no)

Regards,
Rajani

- We did testing on IE9 and its lot better. But users cant immediately upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the code `fnActionsGridComplete`. I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) which explains why it's very important to use `gridview: true` and reduce the number of changes of DOM elements of the page.

What you try to do seems could be implemented by adding `cellattr` to the column `"IsItemNew"`. The code could be about the following

```js
cellattr: function (rowId, value) {
    // additional parameter of cellattr: rawObject, cm, rdata are optional
    if (value === "Y") {
        return ' style="font-weight:bold;"';
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can add `class` attribute instead of `style` and define `font-weight: bold` in the class.

I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408355/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048865/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935) etc. If you would need to set some properties on the whole row instead of the cell only you can use `rowattr` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935)).

If you would include `gridview: true` and use `cellattr`, `rowattr` or custom formatters you would see that the performance of the grid will be on absolutely another level.