# Show hidden data with mouseover in a particular colum of Jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

how can display items of a hidden colmodel when mouse over another column which shows only some part of the data. in user column i have many names, i only display first user name and rest the count. so i passed the full names as hidden. I want to display that names according to the mouseover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand the problem you can solve it by usage `cellattr` callback which defines `title` attribute based on the value of another (hidden) column. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408355/315935) for the corresponding code example.